# onFocusChange() acts like textChanged()

Tags: android, android-edittext, onfocus

I added an OnFocusChangeListener to my EditText so that I can do some validation on the value when the user clicks outside, or tabs out of, the EditText view:

```
  EditText myEditText = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.myedittext);
  myEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
  @Override
  public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
    EditText editText = (EditText)view;
    if (!hasFocus) {
      validate(editText.getText().toString());
    }
  }
}
```

However, it appears the onFocusChange() method is being called like a textChanged() method.  It's getting called every time I enter anything into the text field.  I tried this on both a 2.2 simulator and my own hardware device and they act the same.

I would appreciate any insight on how the OnFocusChangeListener should work and why it's working the way it is for me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First, you shouldn't have to redeclare the EditText editText in the `onFocusChange` method. myEditText should be a class variable that is set in the `onCreate` method. I think your code is treating it a two separate instances.

And try adding the `OnEditorActionListener`

```
myEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            validate(myEditText.getText().toString());
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the problem and found no detail information about handling `onFocusChange()` together with `EditText` text changed.

I'm sure `onFocusChange()` get called every time `[editText].setText()` is being called. In my case I want to validate the input text after the input is done or `hasFocus()` returns false. That validation is followed by setting the text agian. So these 2 processes `onFocusChange()` and `[editText].setText()` are interrupting each other.

**Solution** [Knowing when Edit text is done being edited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099814/knowing-when-edit-text-is-done-being-edited)

By using something like this

```
 meditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {

                yourcalc();

                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```